# You have (3^2 + 2^3 + 2^2) Guesses Left. Figure out the Last one

Tags: pattern, no-computers, letter-sequence

Getting bored of all the sequences (including mine)?

Here is a little different one for you.

> What is the last one in the following:
>
> C, H, O, P, S, ?

Tell me why?

Comment: Is the [tag:no-computers] tag necessary?

Comment: People can search for patterns just they do in oeis..that’s why I put it in..anyway most of my sequences wont be found in oeis.

Comment: But OEIS is the online encyclopedia of **integer** sequences, and this is not an integer sequence.

Comment: That would be a computer search..anyway I err on the side of caution .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is

> N

Reasoning

> These are chemical symbols representing the six most important chemical elements whose covalent combinations make up most biological molecules on Earth ("six elements of life"): **c**arbon, **h**ydrogen, **o**xygen, **p**hosphorus, **s**ulphur, **n**itrogen

Comment: Any explanation for the order? (i.e. why wasn't it H, C, ?, O, P, S in the puzzle?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor My thinking was that it's supposed to read as a word: CHOPS

Comment: Congrats!! You got it.

Comment: I didn’t want it to be obvious and also like hexoomino says, I needed a nice sounding word rather than random letters.

Comment: Huh, I don't usually think of P and S in that list. But that's probably Frederick Pohl's fault.

Comment: Without giving a spoiler, this distribution exhibits bias towards a certain, umm, planet...

Comment: @smci Unless you can name another planet with its own kind of <spoiler-redacted>, it's not really bias :)

Answer (score 16):

The answer is indeed

> N for Nitrogen

but let me take a stab at the title:

> $3^2 + 2^3 + 2^2 = 21$; "guesses" more or less sounds as "gas is" so "21 gas is left". Air consists of 79% Nitrogen and 21% other gasses.

Comment: Great find..but it is unintended correct coincidence..my reasoning was there are only 21 letters left..I just put it mathematically for fun..

Comment: wow, almost seemed impossible to be a coincidence!

Answer (score 7):

This is a long shot, but the title could be a hint towards it.

> W

because

> 3, 8, 15, 16, 19, 23, ... is the sequence of numbers whose base-5 representation contains **no 2's and exactly one 3**. ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C8%2C15%2C16%2C19&language=english&go=Search).)

Comment: I heeded your suggestions and went non-mathematical for a change..title Is just a fancy way of expressing two neighbors.

Comment: Sometimes you wonder how such a sequence found its way to OEIS...

Comment: @Evargalo Everything is on OEIS, I guess.

Comment: Not really..I developed more than 100 sequences specifically not to be found in oeis for mainly security management and cryptographic purposes.

Comment: I don’t think the last letter corresponds to the tags you have added in..

Comment: @Uvc What? The tags simply describe the puzzle: it's a sequence of letters ([tag:letter-sequence]) where one needs to find the next letter ([tag:pattern]).

Comment: May be I am wrong..here it corresponds to fact based answer not sequence based.

Comment: @Uvc Huh??? All answers, including those about sequences, should be based on facts.

Comment: Wow this is impressively geeky...

Answer (score 5):

According to the answer of hexomino I would say

> N

Because

> This is the writing order of chemical formula according to the [Hill System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_formula#Hill_system), where atoms in molecules have to be named in this particular order.

Comment: Right, but that's just a consequence (of the pattern mentioned by @hexomino et al.) rather than a cause.